# Buttons created through jquery don't respond to clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I've come to understand using $('.whatever').click() only works for items created initially. Additional items won't respond in the correct fashion. I was then directed to using something like $('.whatever).on('click', myFunction()). However, I'm not detecting any difference, as newly created items are not called.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstration my example code: http://jsfiddle.net/atrus6/zaKZN/

My initial input plus 'Kill' will work in the correct fashion, however any additional 'input + kill's will not not do anything. Am I incorrectly using .on() or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.rmv').live('click', function() {
    console.log('here');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click', '.rmv', function() {
    console.log('here');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaKZN/18/)

Comment: Live() is deprecated as of 1.7, however the second one worked (when I didn't have document in quotes)

Comment: Works for me, check the demo, didnt you mean something like that

Answer (score 1):

live() works as you seem to expect on() to work, but is deprecated.

on() only works for elements that exist when on() is invoked.
However, you can use it like live() by binding on() to an element that
will be the parent of the newly created elements, and specifying a selector.

So, for example,

```
$('body').on('click', '.rmv', function() {
    console.log('here');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly created elements aren't binded automatically to your click handler because they are created after you define that biding. One solution might be to bind the new elements as they are created.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zaKZN/17/

```
$('.rmv').on('click', remove);

$('.add').click(add);

function remove()
{
    console.log('here');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
}

function add()
{
    var add = "<div class='input-append'>";
    add += "<input type='text' name='br'>";
    add += "<button class='btn btn-danger rmv'><i class='icon-minus'>Kill</i></button></div>";
    $(this).before(add);

    //Bind newly created elements
    $('.rmv').on('click', remove);

    return false;
}
```